# Razor class library not compatible with monoandroid13.0 only supports net6.0 issue?

Tags: c#, xamarin, blazor, blazor-webassembly, maui

I was making a sample using this https://jspuij.github.io/BlazorWebView.Docs/pages/prepare.html?tabs=createpage-1%2Caddpage-1

But after I built at the end I found only one issue [here is the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeCl7.png)

I tried some solutions but don't get the result

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory. You are targeting `monoandroid`. However, the package you are consuming is targeting `net6.0`.

These are not compatible with each other.

You would need to migrate your Android project to target `net6.0-android` or higher.